# How to read only column A value from excel using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

How to read only Column A value from excel using nodejs(node-xlsx) ? Please advise. After reading all the column values then loop through to search from other source.

```
var xlsx = require('node-xlsx');
var obj = xlsx.parse(__dirname + '/test.xlsx'); 
var obj = xlsx.parse(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/test.xlsx')); 
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try other npm package called: `xlsx`:

```
'use strict';

const _ = require('lodash');
const xlsx = require('xlsx');

const workbook = xlsx.readFile('./data/pv.xlsx');
const worksheet = workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]];

const columnA = [];

for (let z in worksheet) {
  if(z.toString()[0] === 'A'){
    columnA.push(worksheet[z].v);
  }
}

console.log(columnA);
```

Comment: collection return as undefined

Comment: @user2848031 try it now

Comment: This is an older answer, and it did help, but the whole "let z" didn't feel comfortable. Also, this would match column "AA". Here's a one-liner update that would only get the values from column "A":
 `const columnA = Object.keys(worksheet).filter(x => /^A\d+/.test(x)).map(x => worksheet[x].v)`

Answer (score 2):

```
const XLSX = require("xlsx");

const workbook = XLSX.readFile("DummyExcel.xlxs"); //read the file
const worksheet = workbook.Sheets["Execution Summary"]; //get the worksheet by name. you can put sheet id also

//print the value of desired cell or range of cell
console.log(
  "worksheet:",
  XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, {
    raw: true,
    range: "B5:B10",
      defval: null,
  })
);
```